# Replace multiple occurences of a string pattern in data table

Tags: r, string, design-patterns, datatable

I have a data table where one of the column contains characters (ID). Some of its rows have a certain pattern (AB_). I would like to replace them with NA using a data.table solution.
Input:

```
dt <- data.table(
ID = c("AB_1","AB_2","b","AB_3","a","c"),
col2 = 1:6,
col3 = 7:12)
```

Output:

```
dt <- data.table(
ID = c("NA","NA","b","NA","a","c"),
col2 = 1:6,
col3 = 7:12)
```

thank you

Comment: `dt[grepl("AB_",ID),ID := NA]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt <- data.table(
  ID = c("AB_1","AB_2","b","AB_3","a","c"),
  col2 = 1:6,
  col3 = 7:12)
```

one possible solution:

```
 dt[grepl("AB_",ID),ID := NA]
```

One other

```
 dt[,ID := gsub("AB_{0-9}",NA,ID)]
```